# When will Arena's Workshop: Uncharted Paths be held?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-arena, events

In [MTG Arena: State of the Game — February 2020](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/magic-digital/mtg-arena-state-game-february-2020-06#workshop), Wizards introduced a three-part workshop series: *Power and Glory, Heroes of Theros,* and *Uncharted Paths*.

I see on [the Arena events calendar](https://magic.wizards.com/en/mtgarena/events) that *Power and Glory* is scheduled for February 24–26, followed by *Heroes of Theros* for March 2–4. However I can't see the date for *Uncharted Paths*. When will it be scheduled for, or has it already happened?

Answer (score 3):

The event is not featured on the Wizards calendar, but it is listed on [the draftsim.com Arena schedule](https://draftsim.com/mtg-arena-schedule/) and will be **March 9–11 2020**. It follows on neatly in the schedule, but I don't know why it was missed on the official site.